# Why does rails change the type of the attribute _was value after it is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an attribute in my model that is stored as text but interpreted as a rational. I have this method to handle that:

```
def start
  read_attribute(:start).to_r
end
```

When I set the `start` attribute to a new value, the `start_was` helper method returns a string, instead of a rational, but before I do so, it returns the correct value. Why?

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3p194 :001 > d = Day.find(55)
  Day Load (8.7ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days" WHERE "days"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 55]]
 => #<Day id: 55, date: "2012-03-30", start: "1/2", finish: "2/2", created_at: "2012-09-18 15:16:42", updated_at: "2012-09-19 08:20:41", day_year_id: 1> 

1.9.3p194 :002 > d.start_was
 => (1/2) 

1.9.3p194 :003 > d.start=0
 => 0 

1.9.3p194 :004 > d.start_was
 => "1/2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is this method in ActiveModel (activemodel-3.2.8\lib\active_model\dirty.rb)

```
# Handle <tt>*_was</tt> for +method_missing+.
def attribute_was(attr)
  attribute_changed?(attr) ? changed_attributes[attr] : __send__(attr)
end
```

As you see, if attribute was not actually changed it just calls its own getter, in your case hitting your `start` method which does the transformation. But if the attribute is actually changed, it reads its raw value from the `changed_attributes` storage.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect, if annoying, sense. :)

Comment: Thankfully I can call `to_r` on an already `Rational` so easy to work around.